# AutoCompleteTextView not workng

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a billing application, shall save the items into the array list at first later on i tried using the AutoCompleteTextView to fetch the items whch i have added to the Arraylist, but as of now i'm unable to fetch any data from the arraylist. I thought like maybe there could be any error but i couldnt find it anywhere cause maybe i might have missed something in my adapter. So could anyone help me on this one? Thanks

This is my adapter

```
public class AutoSuggestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context mCtx;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> items;
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> tempItems;
    private List<ItemModel> suggestions;

    public AutoSuggestAdapter(Context mCtx, int resource, ArrayList<ItemModel> items) {
        super(mCtx, resource, 0, items);
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;
        tempItems = new ArrayList<>();
        suggestions = new ArrayList<ItemModel>(items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }
        ItemModel item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null && view instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) view).setText((CharSequence) item);
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return itemFilter;
    }

    Filter itemFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = (String) resultValue;
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (ItemModel items : tempItems) {
                    if (items.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(items);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<String> filterList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (String item : filterList) {
                    add(item);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Added the AutoCompleteTextView in xml as

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/additemtobillname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text2"
            android:hint="Enter Item Name" />
```

And in the activty declared as

```
AutoCompleteTextView actv = findViewById(R.id.additemtobillname);
        final ArrayList<ItemModel>[] itemlist = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList<>()};
        AutoSuggestAdapter adapter = new AutoSuggestAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemlist[0]);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
        actv.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: there is no data in `itemlist[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You are making use of various objects without initial values.

First i saw was **tempItems** which was never assigned a value before usage under **performFiltering** method.

Assign value of items to tempItems under the constructor

```
//tempItems = new ArrayList<>();
tempItems = items;
```

Or loop through items object inside performFiltering instead of tempItems object

```
for (ItemModel item : items) {
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(item);
                    }
                }
```

Furthermore **itemList** is empty before calling **itemlist[0]**. That would throw a runtime error (ArrayOutOfBound).

Add atleast one value to the array object before referencing its zero index.

```
AutoCompleteTextView actv = findViewById(R.id.additemtobillname);
            final ArrayList<ItemModel>[] itemlist = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList<>()};

    //add value
    itemlist.add(new ArrayList<ItemModel>());

    //pass use to adapter
            AutoSuggestAdapter adapter = new AutoSuggestAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemlist[0]);
            actv.setAdapter(adapter);
            actv.setThreshold(1);
```